# Complex LastNonEmpty get last action for every member per day

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

Let's say we have fact table of operators logs (~50 million rows) with the following fields:

- **Event**, **Client**, **Date**.
- Event1, Client1, 2016-10-10
- Event1, Client1, 2016-10-11

And three dimensions: Event (~20 rows), Client(~500 000 rows), Date(~2000 rows).

I want to see last action for every client in certain day. So in report I want to choose a certain day and get the result.

The report will look like:

- **Event**, **CountOfClients**
- Event1, 200000
- Event2, 150000
- Event3, 100000

**Current workaround**: Totally DWH, I calculate last event every day for every client and it's huge (500 000 * 2000 = 1 000 000 000 rows).

**MDX workarouds**: I tried to reuse [Chris Webb's idea](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2011/03/24/last-ever-non-empty-a-new-fast-mdx-approach/), but it's still be slow to re-aggregate for every client, nevertheless it was the fastest MDX workaround so far.

I guess there are some other workarounds to dynamically get the result without huge tables fillings.

MDX limitations:

- LastNonEmpty aggregation can't get the result if we select members on
  axis (we need only one - last event).
- We have to check whole history till today and use recalculating set    {NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER} for every client, however I found a dirty hack to to speed it up by using VisualTotal within MDX Calculations. A side effect: [Date].[Date].[All] member is recalculated for all measures within reports.

`With
[Measures].[CustomersWithSalesTillToday] as
SUM(
    VisualTotals([Date].[Date].[All] + NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER),
    NULL
)
+
SUM(
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].Members,
    IIF(
        ([Date].[Date].[All],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) > 0,
        1,
        NULL
    )
)`

DWH limitations:

- Huge table, BackData can be changed, processing time raises day by
  day.

Actually there are some of other experiences in this area I may share, but I hope you got my idea.

Comment: Just to add clarity to this question, request you to 1) add the full query in the question and 2) give an example of the data in the fact table.